# Creating a belongs_to relationship with a multiple field index instead of primary key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord, rails-activerecord

### Context

Imagine the following: I have a model `Sector` that contains an ID as primary key (which I want to keep) and that model has two attributes that are unique together and with an index about their location (ie. Sectors cannot be in the same position).

```
# Table name: sector
#
#  id      :bigint           not null, primary key
#  x       :bigint           not null
#  y       :bigint           not null
#  attrA   :datetime
#  attrB   :boolean
#  attrC   :string
#  (etc)
#
# Indexes
#
#  sector_index         (x,y) UNIQUE
```

Now, let's imagine that we have objects that are at a specific location, and that location may change (objects move around).

```
# Table name: object
#
#  id  :bigint           not null, primary key
#  x   :bigint           not null
#  y   :bigint           not null
```

### Problem

**How to join these tables efficiently??**

### Option 1 - ID as foreign key

The obvious off the shelf solution to join these two tables is to create a `belongs_to :sector`, which would need a `sector_id` foreign key. However, every time we need to update a large number of objects' positions, we would need to query the sector table to get the ID of the sector containing X and Y. (eg, let's say we need to move all objects 3 sections in the Y direction)

### Option 2: Ditching the `belongs_to` and use a model attribute

The other choice is to have

```
class Object < ApplicationRecord
  def sector
    Sector.where(x: x, y:y)
  end
end
```

The obvious disadvantage is that this does not allow any preloading or table joins, and will result in n+1

### Option 3 - using Gem composite primary key

The gem Composite primary keys - https://github.com/composite-primary-keys/composite_primary_keys - allows the use composite primary keys, but I would like to keep the ID as a primary key.

### Question

Can we somehow use the unique index to create a belongs_to association that can take advantage of the Rails ActiveRecord helpers and methods such as `includes` and `preloads` and `joins`? Maybe create additional (non primary) composite key in the Sector?

### Other references I found:

Shopify composite primary keys - https://shopify.engineering/how-to-introduce-composite-primary-keys-in-rails

Comment: For option #2, why does it create n+1. Is it correct that you are trying to find all objects in a sector OR did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: @Ankit for option #2 it does not do n+1 on select of a single object, but you lose the option to do joins on related objects, includes and preloads. So it still limits things a bit. For example, lets say I have a list Objects, and I need to query all the attributes of the sector for all of them.